# Using ORDER BY command in an UPDATE SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking at updating an `item number` column from a number of rows in a table (which match a particular Product ID & type) but I want to order the rows by numbers in a 'Seqnumber' column then the item number column start at 1 and count each row sequentially by 1.

Using the code below I have been able to select the product id and type I want and update the item number column with sequentially increasing values, however I don't know how I can order the required rows?

```
DECLARE @id nvarchar(6)
SET @id = 0

UPDATE Table1
SET @id = Table1.ItemNumber = @id + 1
WHERE Product = '5486' AND Table1.Type = 'C'
```

I know you can't use the `ORDER BY` command within the `UPDATE` command without using it as a sub-query. But I'm not sure how I should include this in the above code?

I think I need to incorporate the code below but not sure what the `SELECT` statement should be and when I try I can't get it to work?

```
DECALRE @id nvarchar(6)
SET @id = 0

UPDATE Table1
SET @id = TABLE1.ItemNumber = @id + 1
FROM (SELECT TOP (??)* FROM Table1 
      WHERE Product = '5486' AND Table1.Type ='C' 
      ORDER BY Table1.SeqNumber ASC
```

Comment: `DECLARE @id nvarchar(6)
SET @id = 0
UPDATE Table1 ....`used like this is invalid MySQL code looks to me you are using sql server as database. TOP is also invalid MySQL code

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to build a CTE with the values you want from the table and just update the CTE

```
declare @Table1 table (Product varchar(4), [Type] varchar(1), SeqNumber int, ItemNumber int)
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES 
('5486', 'C', 3, 0),
('5486', 'C', 2, 0);



with cte as (
    select  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SeqNumber) rn
    from    @Table1 
    where   Product = '5486' and Type ='C' 
)
Update cte 
set    ItemNumber = rn
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SET @id = 0;

UPDATE Table1
    SET @id = Table1.ItemNumber = (@id := @id + 1)
    WHERE Product = 5486 and Table1.Type = 'C'
    ORDER BY Table1.seqnumber;
```

You cannot use `ORDER BY` with a `JOIN`, so you need to initialize the variable before the `update`.

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE sales_data
SET ID = ID + 1
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

Comment: Invalid syntax... and if you're just adding a 1 to the current value, the order would be irrelevant as well.